# Is Android Backup Google Transport working?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I'm trying to implement the Android Backup Agent in my app.
Using the local transport it works with success. But trying with Google transport:
com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService

It does not works, don't even call my BackupAgentHelper onCreate method.

Is this Backup Transport Service working? I have been trying for 2 weeks to solve it. I had also followed all the instructions at Android developers page.

Does anyone knows if there is any "secret" step that I'm missing to work with Google Transport?

Comment: There are 2 transports:
  android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
* com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService

On LocalTransport the backup works, but on BackupTransportService doesn't.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem.  Local works fine, but with GMS the settings are not restored when re-installing the app.  Will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Pushbit, thaks. I had gave up on this because I had not found anything to solve this issue. Please share good news if you have it sooner. Good luck!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I seem to have the same problem

Comment: No @ChrisFawcett. In fact I did not try anymore. I gave up, but it was one year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Manifest file to see if under application you have android:allowBackup="true" as well as android:backupAgent having the correct path to your projects FileBackupAgent. Also, your meta-data should have your registered key, such as android:value="your-registerd-key"

Make sure your device is connected to a Wi-Fi network. Also, make sure in your device Settings, the Backup and Reset needs to have "Back up my data" checked, and "Backup account" has a valid gmail account, and "Automatic restore" is checked.

In addition, in a command window, your transport settings should be: *com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService

You can see this by typing: bmgr list transports If transport is set to local, then enter: bmgr transport com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService

Other bmgr commands to use to "kick" start your backup in https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard are:

```
bmgr enabled 
bmgr wipe "your package in your manifest file"
bmgr backup "your package in your manifest file"
bmgr run
```

Refresh your https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard to see the latest backup timestamp